# js - Freeze current properties

Tags: javascript, object

### Is there a way to freeze existing properties of an object allowing to add new properties to it?

Hello World,
I've got an `window.foo` object with properties `bar=1` and `qux=2`.
I need these to be frozen and unrewritable.

It's easy using this code:

```
var foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo,"bar",{ "value":1 });
Object.defineProperty(foo,"qux",{ "value":2 });
```

But this can be easily overwritten by `window.foo={"bar":3};`.

**Is there any way?**

Thanks :)

Comment: If you have frozen the *object properties*, you can still write to the `foo` *variable*. No difference between your solutions in that regard.

Comment: @m93a You're mistaken, using `Object.freeze(foo)` doesn't prevent you from doing `foo = undefined`, or `foo = {'firstProp':'pileOfCrap'}`

Comment: @Bergi & Adam: You're right, my fault :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think I've got it.
The key is that non-writable property which is an object still can be modified (adding properties etc.) because the "non-writable thing" about it is just the object's address.
I didn't know this, now it turns out it's quite easy!

```
//non-writable window.foo
Object.defineProperty(window,"foo",{
 "enumerable":true,
 "value":{}
});

//Non-writable foo.bar
Object.defineProperty(window.foo,"bar",{
 "enumerable":true,
 "value":1
});

//Non-writable foo.qux
Object.defineProperty(window.foo,"qux",{
 "enumerable":true,
 "value":2
});
```

And here it is! :)
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can define all current properties to make them not writable and not configurable, which will accomplish the same task.

```
Object.prototype.freezeAllCurrentProperties = function() {
  for(i in this) {
   if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     Object.defineProperty(this,i,{writable:false,configurable:false});
   }
  }
}

var x = {'firstProp':'a string'};
x.freezeAllCurrentProperties();
delete x['firstProp']; //returns false (thanks to configurable:false)
x['firstProp'] = false; //doesn't change (thanks to writable:false)
x.newProp = true; //adds newProp to x
```

Comment: Read my question carefully! You can _de facto_ rewrite them using `x={'firstProp':'another string'};`

Comment: Further, it sounds like what you really want to do is to wrap an isolated scope around your object so it can only be accessed through an API, which enforces the freezing for you....then again. this is just JavaScript, people can always just overwrite your accessor methods if you're that concerned about it.